# ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [^^^RP09.PEGP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psparse-330)

Tags: boot

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [^^^RP09.PEGP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psparse-330)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PC10.LPCB.EC._QD1, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psparse-516)
```

Every time I try to boot my laptop, these two lines error appear three times and won't let my laptop boot.

The last thing I was doing was trying to install atk.

LAPTOP: MSI Prestige PS42 Modern 8MO-i5
OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please have a look at [Bug 1610727 - ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psargs-330) and others ](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1610727) It seems that many users have these unspecific [tag:ACPI] errors and bug fixing isn't complete, yet. I have also tons of ACPI errors on my system (ASUSTeK P8Z68-V LX) and I can cold boot, but can't do a warm boot after wakeup. Weeks ago it was working, but with last updates it is no longer warm booting.